# How to make a middleware to intercept data from http request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

How can i use the iActionFilter to be able to intercept the http request data and save them into variables as well as the respond before  being returned to the user.

Comment: IActionFilter and Middleware are different.  You should use Middleware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what are you trying to do? If you could please share a code example, that would be great and someone can help you in a better way. Also, you may find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helpful.